# Why does my KeyListener not work?

Tags: java, jframe, keylistener, keyevent, event-listener

My KeyListener isn't registering that any keys are being pressed, what can i do to fix this? i have tried using keycodes instead of the VK_DOWN format but that doesn''t make a difference. i am not using a jpanel..

```
     import javax.swing.*;
     import java.awt.event.*;
     public class SnakeFrame extends JFrame
   {
final int FRAME_WIDTH = 800;
final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 700;
private SnakeComponent scene;
class KeyPressListener implements KeyListener
{
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
    {
        int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
        switch( keyCode ) { 
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
            // handle up 
            System.out.println("Hello");
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
            // handle down 
            scene.a("d");
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
            // handle left
            scene.a("l");
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT :
            // handle right
            scene.a("r");
        }
        KeyListener key = new KeyPressListener();
        scene.addKeyListener(key);
    } 

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){}

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
}
class TimerListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        scene.moveSnake();
        scene.eaten();
        scene.gameOver();
    }
}
public SnakeFrame()
{
    scene = new SnakeComponent();
    add(scene);

    setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);

    KeyListener key = new KeyPressListener();
    scene.addKeyListener(key);

    ActionListener listener = new TimerListener();
    final int DELAY = 80;
    Timer t = new Timer(DELAY, listener);
    t.start();

}
```

}

I have tried if/else statements instead of the switch case and that doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

`KeyListener` needs two things to work, it needs the component it is registered to to be `focsuable` AND have current keyboard focus, before it will generate keys, this is a known limitation to the `KeyListener`s

As with every other question on the subject, the recommended solution is to use the [Key Bindings API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) which has been designed, amongst other things, to resolve this issue and give you control to determine at what focus level it should generate events